# Defining custom types in Pydantic v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pydantic

The code below used to work in Pydantic V1:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CustomInt(int):
    """Custom int."""
    pass


class CustomModel(BaseModel):
    """Custom model."""
    custom_int: CustomInt
```

Using it with Pydantic V2 will trigger an error. The error can be resolved by including `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in `model_config`, but is there a better solution?

Kindly note that the [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#custom-data-types) suggest using `Annotated`, but that doesn't allow defining custom docstring, which is desirable in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but as a workaround, it's possible to redefine the base model to automatically allow arbitrary types:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)


class CustomInt(int):
    """Custom int."""

    pass


class CustomModel(CustomBaseModel):
    """Custom model."""

    custom_int: CustomInt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using a class which inherits from a type by [defining core schema on the class](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#customizing-validation-with-__get_pydantic_core_schema__):

```py
from typing_extensions import Any
from pydantic import GetCoreSchemaHandler, TypeAdapter
from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema


class CustomInt(int):
    """Custom int."""
    ...
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, source_type: Any, handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler
    ) -> CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.no_info_after_validator_function(cls, handler(int))
```

> Note: These are advanced methods and may have undesirable side effects. Further documentation here: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/pydantic_core/

Comment: Related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100890/pydantic-v2-custom-type-validators-with-info/77108459#77108459

Comment: Interesting... not sure if most would agree, but the syntax of `Annotated` does not look very pythonic...

Comment: That's a deep rabbit hole: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#relevant-peps