# Pydantic v2 custom type validators with info

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I'm trying to update my code to pydantic v2 and having trouble finding a good way to replicate the custom types I had in version 1. I'll use my custom date type as an example. The original implementation and usage looked something like this:

```
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel


class CustomDate(date):
    # Override POTENTIAL_FORMATS and fill it with date format strings to match your data
    POTENTIAL_FORMATS = []
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate_date
        
    @classmethod
    def validate_date(cls, field_value, values, field, config) -> date:
        if type(field_value) is date:
            return field_value
        return to_date(field.name, field_value, cls.POTENTIAL_FORMATS, return_str=False)

class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    class MyDate(CustomDate):
        POTENTIAL_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d']
    dt: MyDate
```

I tried to follow the [official docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#as-a-method-on-a-custom-type) and the examples laid out [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/5581) below and it mostly worked, but the `info` parameter does not have the fields I need (`data` and `field_name`). Attempting to access them gives me an AttributeError.

```
info.field_name
*** AttributeError: No attribute named 'field_name'
```

Both the `Annotated` and `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` approaches have this issue

```
from datetime import date
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator
from pydantic_core import core_schema  

class CustomDate:
    POTENTIAL_FORMATS = []

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, field_value, info):
        if type(field_value) is date:
            return field_value
        return to_date(info.field_name, field_value, potential_formats, return_str=False)

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, source, handler) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.general_plain_validator_function(cls.validate)


def custom_date(potential_formats):
    """
    :param potential_formats: A list of datetime format strings
    """
    def validate_date(field_value, info) -> date:
        if type(field_value) is date:
            return field_value
        return to_date(info.field_name, field_value, potential_formats, return_str=False)
    CustomDate = Annotated[date, BeforeValidator(validate_date)]
    return CustomDate


class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    class MyDate(CustomDate):
        POTENTIAL_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d']
    dt: MyDate
    dt2: custom_date(['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d'])
```

If I just include the `validate_date` function as a regular `field_validator` I get `info` with all the fields I need, it's only when using it with custom types that I see this issue. How do I write a custom type that has access to previously validated fields and the name of the field being validated?

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76937581/10693596 (h/t @Yaakov Bressler).

Comment: Q: Where are you importing `to_date` from?

Comment: It's some custom code that iterates through the formats and parses things with some logging. Code fails on the `info.field_name` access so it's not relevant, omitted to keep things shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 2.4 you can get the field_name and data together. See the updated docs [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#access-to-field-name).

Now the first version of my custom data type looks like:

```
class CustomDate:
    POTENTIAL_FORMATS = []

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, field_value, info):
        if type(field_value) is date:
            return field_value
        return to_date(info.field_name, field_value, cls.POTENTIAL_FORMATS, return_str=False)

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, source, handler) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.with_info_before_validator_function(
            cls.validate, handler(date), field_name=handler.field_name
        )
```

Where all I needed to change was which core_schema validator function I was using. The second version of my custom data type (the one using Annotated) now works as is with no changes.

#### Before Pydantic 2.4

It looks like accessing `info.data` and `info.field_name` inside a custom type validator is not currently possible in v2 according to [this feature request](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7448).

If all you need is `info.data`, then it looks like you can define your validator with `core_schema.field_before_validator_function` (I'd guess all the `field_*` validators work), although you will need to make up a field name:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Annotated, List, Any, Callable


from pydantic import ValidationError, BaseModel, Field, BeforeValidator, field_validator, GetCoreSchemaHandler
from pydantic_core import core_schema, CoreSchema


def fn(v: str, info: core_schema.ValidationInfo, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
    try:
        print(f'Validating {info.field_name}')
        return info.data['use_this']
    except AttributeError as err:
        return 'No data'


class AsFieldB4Method(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, source_type: Any, handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler, *args, **kwargs
    ) -> CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.field_before_validator_function(fn, 'not_the_real_field_name', core_schema.str_schema())


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    use_this: str
    core_schema_field_b4_method: AsFieldB4Method  # Partially works
```

From the comments, it sounds like the pydantic team want to make it work with non-field validators and to make accessing `info.field_name` possible, so hopefully that happens. I'll update this answer when the change happens, but check that link in case I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach would be to perform validation via an [Annotated type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#composing-types-via-annotated). However, there are cases where you may need a [fully customized type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#customizing-validation-with-__get_pydantic_core_schema__).

### Annotated Field

(The easy way)

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
from functools import partial
from typing import Any, List
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from pydantic import TypeAdapter
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator


def try_parse_date(v: Any, allowed_formats: List[str]) -> Any:

    if isinstance(v, str):
        for fmt in allowed_formats:
            try:
                return datetime.strptime(v, fmt).date()
            except ValueError:
                continue
    else:
        return v


CustomDate = Annotated[
    date,
    BeforeValidator(
        partial(
            try_parse_date,
            allowed_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d', '%Y_%m_%d']
        )
    )
]
```

Here's a test which ensures expected behavior:

```py
def test_custom_type():
    values = [
        "2023-06-01", "2023/06/01", "2023_06_01",
        date(2023, 6, 1)
    ]
    expected = date(2023, 6, 1)

    ta = TypeAdapter(CustomDate)
    result = [ta.validate_python(x) for x in values]
    assert all(x==expected for x in result)
```

---

### Fully Customized Type

The issue you are experiencing relates to the order of which pydantic executes validation. Given that `date` format has its own core schema (ex: will validate a timestamp or similar conversion), you will want to execute your validation *prior* to the core validation.

> Related Answer (with simpler code): [Defining custom types in Pydantic v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76937581/defining-custom-types-in-pydantic-v2/77092123#77092123)

To solve this, you will need to define `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` in your custom type. I've [chained](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/pydantic_core_schema/#pydantic_core.core_schema.chain_schema) the schema validation below, which allows multiple types to be merged into one (ex: say you want to convert a `datetime` into a date, you can do so in the chain). I've also used [`general_plain_validator_function`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/pydantic_core_schema/#pydantic_core.core_schema.general_plain_validator_function) which doesn't need a specific schema to operate (the most vanilla option).

#### Code for creating custom Date type in Pydantic V2:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
from typing import Any, List

from pydantic import BaseModel, GetCoreSchemaHandler
from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema



class CustomDate(date):
    """Custom date"""

    allowed_formats: List[str] = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d']


    @classmethod
    def try_parse_date(cls, v: Any, info: core_schema.ValidationInfo) -> Any:

        if isinstance(v, str):
            for fmt in cls.allowed_formats:
                try:
                    return datetime.strptime(v, fmt).date()
                except ValueError:
                    continue
        else:
            return v

    @classmethod
    def truncate_datetime(cls, v: Any, info: core_schema.ValidationInfo) -> Any:
        """If a datetime value is provided, truncate to a date"""
        if isinstance(v, datetime):
            return v.date()
        else:
            return v


    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, source_type: Any, handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler
    ) -> CoreSchema:

        return core_schema.chain_schema(
            [
                core_schema.general_plain_validator_function(
                    function=cls.truncate_datetime,
                ),
                core_schema.general_plain_validator_function(
                    function=cls.try_parse_date,
                )

            ]
        )
```

#### You can use the defined type, or customize `allow_formats` by subclassing the type:

```py
class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    class MyDate(CustomDate):
        allowed_formats = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d', '%Y_%m_%d']

    dt: MyDate
```

Here's a quick test which shows things are working:

```
def test_model():
    values = [
        "2023-06-01", "2023/06/01", "2023_06_01",
        date(2023, 6, 1), datetime(2023, 6, 1, 1)
    ]
    expected = date(2023, 6, 1)

    data = [ExampleModel(dt=v) for v in values]
    assert all(x.dt == expected for x in data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response unfortunately it doesn’t address my issue. My issue is that I need to use the field_name and data attributes of info and they are not populated. I’m not having a problem getting my custom types working otherwise

Comment: You can access those from `info` in the `try_parse_date` function. @hamdog

Comment: Those attributes don't exist that's the problem. Add some print statements and see for yourself. Traceback I get: 
`Traceback ... in try_parse_date print(info.field_name) AttributeError: No attribute named 'field_name' `

Comment: Instead of using `core_schema.general_plain_validator_function` / `BeforeValidator`, you will want to use `field_validator`

Comment: The issue is -> the validation you are trying to perform takes place independently of the `field` -> it is happening outside the context of the pydantic model. If you want field level control, use a traditional `field_validator` @hamdog

Comment: holy crap they made this complicated for fully customized types.